# Data Annotation Validators with Asp.net Web Form and differences with MS Enterprise Library Validation Block

Tags: asp.net, c, validation, enterprise-library

I use Asp.net 4 and C# in Web Forms with Entity Framework 4.

I need cross cutting Validation for my Entities on the business layer and on the presentation layer.

I read about Data Annotation Validators on MVC, and I think could be a reasonable solution for my web app.

I would like to know if is possible implement it even with Web Forms without many workarounds.

Also I would like to know the main difference with Enterprise Library Validation Block.

Many thanks